# Proposal for new FAQ

Tags: discussion, faq-content

We have been without a proper [FAQ](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for too long.  Based on meta activity and my own understanding of the community we're building here, I have taken the liberty of drafting one, which I have posted as my own answer to this question.

In order to give everybody a chance to weigh in with their votes, suggestions, critiques or even their own drafts, I will leave this proposal open until the 7th of October (two weeks).  Please take full advantage of that time to ensure that our official FAQ actually reflects not only the policy of the site itself, but the interests of the community as a whole.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*This has now been applied to Islam.SE's FAQ*

---

My own proposal for the FAQ is as follows:

> Islam Stack Exchange is for **experts in Islam, students of knowledge, and those interested in Islam on an academic level**.  For the purposes of this site, "Islam" includes all groups that identify themselves as Muslim; do expect to see answers from multiple points of view unless a certain perspective is *explicitly* requested in the question.
>
> **Respect other people's beliefs**, and don't get into arguments about whether any particular group is "right" or "wrong"; we are all here to learn together.
>
> Any questions on the subject of Islam are welcome here, including but not limited to Islamic law and theology, the Islamic texts, or classical Arabic as it pertains to understanding the above.
>
> The following, however, are considered **off-topic** here except where they're shown to be directly relevant to the religion of Islam:
>
> - Cultural practices and behaviour of Muslim communities
> - Politics of Muslim-majority countries
> - The Arabic language itself
>
> It is also important to note that **this is not a fatwa site**.  While questions on the legality of actions (from an Islamic perspective) are welcome, answers may be posted by anybody regardless of training or expertise.  It is important to judge the evidences provided by each answer to the best of your own abilities, and accept such answers at your own risk.

While not exhaustive, the following meta discussions were significantly influential on what I chose to include:

- [Should we tighten our scope?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/761/22)
- [What is the community we're trying to build here?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/691/22)
- [A higher standard for "fatwa" questions?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/383/22)
- [What things need to go in the FAQ?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/333/22)
- [Why Sectarianism is Ruining Your Site](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/275/22)
- [Islam SE: Not a Muslim Peer Support Group](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/189/22)

Comment: Looks good. I would change "students of knowledge" with "those interested in learning about Islam".

Comment: @kaveh that wording would seem to be redundant when followed by "and those interested in Islam on an academic level".  I decided on "students of knowledge" to distinguish between people who are actively dedicated to learning the religion (either self-directed or with a teacher and/or accredited courseload), rather than just the casually interested.

Comment: I see. I think the redundant part is "those interested in Islam on an academic level", sounds like the first category. The main problem with "students of knowledge" is an unusual expression in English (sound like a word by word translation from another language). I think that part needs to be improved. Maybe "Islamic scholars and experts and those interested in learning about Islam ...." where "..." replaced with some quantification.

Comment: ps: I understand your concern however I don't know if it is a good idea in the SE model to restrict the scope to people who are actively learning about Islam.

Comment: @Kaveh Agreed, which is why I also included "interested in Islam on an academic level"; the "on an academic level" distinction in that case is mostly to dissuade the type of casual no-research no-effort questions that are typically frowned upon across the network already.

Comment: I will be the first to admit that that very first sentence was the one that gave me the most trouble, and I'm still not convinced it's perfect.